# Strip JS text and save results to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have the following JS function to pull out all words that start with “#” and replace the css styling of them. I would like to add a url that redirects to a query of all items containing the tag.

How would I save the stripped tags, and then dynamically add it to the url for each one?

```
$('.find-hashtag').each(function(index) {
    var str = $(this).html();
    var edt = str.replace(/(^|\s)(#[A-Za-z]+)/ig, "$1<a href='{% url "hashtagged_item_list” *stored_value_goes_here* %}'>$2</a>");
    $(this).html(edt);
});
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

***What I'm hoping to accomplish:***

```
<p class="find-hashtag">This is sample #html text.</p>

$('.find-hashtag').each(function(index) {
    var str = $(this).html();
    var tag = "html";
    var edt = str.replace(/(^|\s)(#[A-Za-z]+)/ig, "$1<a href='{% url "hashtagged_item_list” tag %}'>$2</a>");
    $(this).html(edt);
});
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what you want exactly? What is `stored_value_goes_here`?

Comment: @manji I just added an example. I want to store the tag value inside of `var tag` and put `tag` in the url where `tag` currently lies.

Answer (score 0):

First, store the url generated by django with a dummy tag. Because django is operating server side and js is client side, they cannot be combined:

```
var url = '{% url "hashtagged_item_list" "dummy" %}';
```

Then,extract the tag and replace 'dummy' with it:

```
var edt = str.replace(/\b#([A-Za-z]+)/ig, function(match, tag) {
             return '<a href="' + url.replace('dummy', tag) + '">#' + tag + '</a>');
          });
```